# Django filter decimal sum after annotate

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a Django query:

```
helpers = project.helpers.annotate(sum=Sum(u'amount'))
```

In database there is one helper with sum decimal value 100. 
When I'm going next code, I have success value:

```
for helper in helpers:
    if helper.sum > Decimal('100'):
        print 'success'
```

But if I'm trying to get a queryset with helpers, I get []:

```
helpers.filter(sum__gt=Decimal('100')
```

`Count` seems to work here but not `Sum`. Why is that?

Comment: Did you try to look at the generated SQL?

Comment: It shows something like `SELECT "profiles_profile"."id", ..., SUM("amount") AS "sum" GROUP BY "profiles_profile"."id", ... HAVING SUM("amount") > 100` that seems legit I think.